# Как вызвать класс из shared library?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Собрал с помощью `cmake` и компилятором `ndk` библиотеку с классами

Указал `loadLibrary`, библиотека для каждой архитектуры и все пути указал. Работает все, но как вызвать класс этой библиотеки? `native class` не принимает. Или еще что-то должно предварительно указываться при сборке самой библиотеки?

Comment: вы хотите из java вызвать C++-класс?

Comment: точнее, из java вызвать класс скомпилированной shared библиотеки под ndk

Comment: native функции - это обычные C-функции, не функции-члены

Comment: @sercxjo, каким образом тогда использовать классы из скомпилированной библиотеки?

Comment: хм.. кажется понял, на примере dll, там же могут храниться только функции, как и в любой другой библиотеке? Значит связывать между C++ и Java можно функции только стандартного типа?

Comment: Тут правила диктует java. C-функция должна быть обычной extern "C" и с определёнными первыми аргументами, а типы остальных тоже из определённого набора (теоретически можно использовать статические функции-члены класса, но это будет менее удобно). А so-библиотека которая получится при компиляции - это особый исполняемый файл динамически загружаемый в адресное пространство java-процесса, там могут быть и свои статические переменные и можно библиотечные функции использовать и загружать другие библиотеки, только исполнение начинается не с main, а с JNI_OnLoad

Answer (score 1):

Для вызова нативного кода, Вам необходимо использовать **JNI**.

Подробнее по ссылке https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html

Comment: про JNI и так понятно, но вопрос в том, чтобы заранее скомпилированную shared библиотеку с классами вызвать из Java